# Android:About the width of the widget in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I wrote the following xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    ......//widgets
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/img"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/pic"
/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in code I wanna get the width of the **img**.But always get **0**.
Why?
Thanks in advance!
PS:Im sorry I have forgoten to add `android:src="..."`;But it still 0!

Comment: how you are getting imagewidth

Answer (score 0):

You get `0` for you width because you:

1. Have `wrap_content` for you `layout_width`
2. You didn't specify `src` attribute, which means there is no image set for you `ImageView`

And because size of empty image is `0` and you have `wrap_content`, you get `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the width in the onCreate method. If thats the case, the UI has not started to be drawn yet and the UI elements are not measured so the imageView.getWidth() should return 0. To get the width in the onCreate method, this should work. Put the code in the onCreate method.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        Log.e("Width",Integer.toString(imageView.getWidth()));

    }
});
```

But you need to first specify an image for the imageview else the width will be 0 as there is nothing to wrap the imageview around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I found that this method could not get the width before I need it.